# Android Studio fails to connect to SVN server - SSL handshake failure

Tags: svn, ssl, android-studio, assembla

I am having issues to connect to SVN server using Android Studio 1.01.
When I try to browse the remote SVN repository I get the following error:

*Subversion: (Accessing URL: https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/whozeincharge) Received fatal alert: handshake_failure Please check Subversion SSL settings (Settings | Version Control | Subversion | Network) Maybe you should specify SSL protocol manually - SSLv3 or TLSv1*

My SVN server is hosted at [www.assembla.com](http://www.assembla.com)

Assembla team blocked the SSL based connections to the SVN server and ask me to use TLS.
See my [conversation](https://helpdesk.assembla.com/customer/en/portal/questions/9927564-unable-to-browse-remote-svn-repository-ssl-handshake-issue?new=9927564) with the assembla support.

Using the SVN CLI, **I am able** to connect to the the server with no issues.
My SVN client version is: 1.8.10 
My Mac info:

> system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType Software:
>
> System Software Overview:
>
> System Version: OS X 10.9.5 (13F34) 
>   Kernel Version: Darwin 13.4.0 
>   Boot Volume: Macintosh HD  
>   Boot Mode: Normal 
>   Computer Name: [name goes here] 
>   User Name: [name goes here>]

After deleting the directory ~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server 
and restarting Android Studio **I was able to browse the remote repository** (using Android Studio) without any issues.
After a while the ssl handshake error came back and the folder ~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server was created on the file system.

My Android Studio SVN configuration:

1. General: Use Command line client: /sw/bin/svn (it points to the 1.8.10 SVN client)
2. General: Use system default Subversion configuration directory: ~/.subversion
3. Network: TLSv1

Please advice

Comment: Well, something's changing the cached details and stopping Android Studio from working. To find out what it is, it's probably worth:

1. Deleting the folder as you have done previously and restarting Android studio
2. Connect once using Android studio so the files are recreated
3. Make a copy of the folder
4. Keep connecting with Android studio until it fails
5. Compare the folder's contents with the copy to see what change is made that stops it connecting

Hopefully that should shed a bit more light on what's going on and give you some idea of whether there's a fix or not.

Comment: Thanks. As for now it works for ~24 hours... so far so good.

Comment: Did you get a solution for the issue? I'm also stuck in the same thing, I'm getting error like "Unable to connect to a repository at URL :{repo name}... Network is unreachable"..but network is fine and sometimes it connects.My svn repo is also at assembla.Do you have any suggestions to figure out whtas going on..Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In Idea or Android Studio, Settings > Version Control > Subversion in General tab, check "Use command line client" with "svn" value.

My error was solved with this solution.

Comment: changing to sslv3 will not work since the SVN server is configured to work with TLS only

Comment: I am using assembla svn with sslv3. It works great. Please try mate.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, the solution that works for me as follow:

1. Open you Terminal through your Android Studio
2. Tape (authentification): chmod 644 ~/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server/*
3. Tape: svn list
4. Tape (accept the certificates, permanently, no need to restart your IDE): p