# Howto setup Assembla (https) svn repository in Android Studio 1.1.0

Tags: svn, ssl, https, android-studio

I am trying to connect with Android Studio 1.1.0 (Mac) to an Assembla Subversion repository. svn commands works just fine in shell.
But in Android Studio all I get are SSL-handshake errors.

I tried Settings - Version Control - Subversion

General

Use Command line client on/off

Use system default Subversion directory on/off

Network SSL-Protocols

All/SSLv3/TLSv1

Result is always SSL-Handshake error. My changes have effect? Do I have to restart every time I do a change? I get no prompt for my user credentials. Could that be the problem? Annoying such basic things don't work.

Comment: This SO question is very similar and proposes few solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27845970/1023562

Comment: Take a look of these answer it may Help you . [How to setup whole process of SVN in Android Studio with every single step](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38612169/5135266)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and I was able to fix this problem on my mac.
I am using Android Studio on Mac and I use assembla.

Solution:
- Copy your assembla url and change it from https to http. It will start working.

Of course make sure Use Command line client on/off as you have already mentioned.